# Adding Generic member variable in Generic Class

Tags: java, generics

Folks,

Is there any easy way to add generic class in non generic class.

Basically the cache manager will have map of Cache class which is implemented with proper generics.

But in below class we return (getCache method) Cache via get method it requires explicit cast at callers place how to avoid it.

e.g.

```
public class CacheManager {
    private Map<String, Cache<?,?>> cacheMap = new HashMap<String, Cache<?,?>>();
    public Cache<?,?> getCache(String cacheName) {
        return cacheMap.get(cacheName);
    }

    public void addCache(String cacheName,Cache<?,?> cache) {
        cacheMap.put(cacheName, cache);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no way to do this without unchecked cast (which in this particular case would be type-safe IMO). You can add more type-safety by adding bounds to your wildcards.

Comment: Are the wildcard types there because a single CacheManager instance will store many different types of Caches? (I.e. why is it not a CacheManager<T, V>?)

Comment: Rohit can you give example how to add more bounds to a  wild card. I am doing explicit cast now (Cache<String,String>)cacheManager.getCache("test")                                                                                                                                                                                                                              Erik you are right I have different different Caches so I cannot use Generics for CacheManager. Please suggest something better.

Comment: You can make the `cacheMap` member's type arguments `Object` (`Map<String,Cache<Object,Object>>`). Then the compiler should stop complaining, but obviously, this solution has [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No (as far as I know).

The problem here is that what you are doing is not type-safe in Java at all. Have a look at this example:

```
import java.util.*;

class ClassCast {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Pair<?, ?>> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put("test", new Pair<String, Integer>("Hello", 5));

        Pair<Double, Double> pair = (Pair<Double, Double>) map.get("test");
    }
}

class Pair<T,V> {
    T a;
    V b;

    Pair(T a, V b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

You would expect a `ClassCastException` here, but it compiles and runs perfectly fine. The reason for this is that the actual class of `Pair<String, Integer>` and `Pair<Double, Double>` is in fact just `Pair` (after type erasure).

To get type safety you have to implement the "Typesafe heterogeneous container pattern" (explained in detail in Effective Java by Josh Bloch). In short, you have to involve the type parameter in the key of your map. Depending on your needs, you might be able to use a class as key directly, otherwise you might have to make a key object.

Example implementation:

```
public class CacheManager {
    private Map<MultiKey, Cache<?,?>> cacheMap = new HashMap<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T,V> Cache<T,V> get(String name, Class<T> t, Class<V> v) {
        // Type-safe since types are encoded in key(i.e. map will not
        // return something with the wrong type), and key is type-checked
        // on insertion.
        return (Cache<T,V>) cacheMap.get(new MultiKey(name, t, v));
    }

    public <T,V> void put(String name, Class<T> t, Class<V> v, Cache<T,V> cache) {
        cacheMap.put(new MultiKey(name, t, v), cache);
    }

    class MultiKey {
        Object[] keys;
        Integer hash = null;

        MultiKey(Object... keys) {
            this.keys = keys;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            if (hash == null) hash = Arrays.hashCode(keys);
            return hash;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (o == null || !(o instanceof MultiKey)) return false;
            return Arrays.equals(keys, ((MultiKey) o).keys);
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
CacheManager mng = new CacheManager();

mng.addCache("SI", String.class, Integer.class, new Cache<String, Integer>());

Cache<String, Integer> cache = mng.getCache("SI", String.class, Integer.class);

System.out.println(cache);
```

It's not pretty, but it is actually type-safe. It can be improved depending on the actual situation though, so you should not use this code as is. For example, if you can get the types from the Cache object you don't need the Class arguments in `addCache`.